# Reference for Dehn Surgery

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, low-dimensional-topology, surgery-theory

I'm looking for an introductory reference for the basics on Dehn surgery on links. Does anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: I think Rolfsen is a good place to start.